# How can I prevent movement of an element from moving other elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

I am using [Gridster.js](https://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/). I would like to prevent one element from moving another.

So when I move one element on top of another, I would like it to prevent dropping it and moving one or more elements, just put it aside like pictures is showing.

[image]

[image]

Is it possible ?

Thank you in advance.